# Scroll bar issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar

I'm currently making a new website for my school and some of my webpages have more content than others and they require scroll bars and when you open these pages, the content moves with a few mm to the left which is really annoying and I can't leave it like that.
Some people advice me to target the html tag and use the overflow-y:scroll property but that way the pages with a few lines of text get a unusable scroll bar - it just looks unprofessional... Is there another option to bypass that issue? I'll be grateful if you can answer me :)

Comment: Please share your code in Jsfiddle?

Comment: Or show us the website

Comment: you can do overflow-y:hidden;

Comment: overflow:auto have u tried..can u share a jsfiddle?

Comment: overflow:auto doesn't work - it's just like without it

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Causes the scroll bar to be visible when it is needed. Otherwise it will stay hidden. Try and see if it works.

Comment: Would be great if you could add some html code in there as well.. even if it is just the basic body so we can see the structure. I take it the overflow-y: auto; didn't work as you're posting code? :)

Comment: I am fairly new to css myself, but the way I have used overflow is to put it in the divs where it is needed. I would however stay away from changing to many things in the html and body tag. You have a wrapper div for things such as that. But for the sites I have made, the scroll will appear on its own as the content of the site expands. My body and html tag generally only contains height: 100%; and perhaps background: #ffffff;

Comment: doesn't your content left move when the scroll bar appears?

Comment: Not that I can see, but it is difficult to see in the small result window. I'd suggest to perhaps use % sizes in some places where it is suitable, perhaps for the width of the right most content or something, parts that can be flexible without ruining the design of the page. CSS can be a bit... whimsical ;) I noticed another issue you are having though, don't put links in paragraphs <p> because they become clickable outside the text on the whole row. Instead use  <span class="something" etc etc>Stuff</span><br> or something like it, might be better ways..

Comment: No no the link was an example :) I just didnt want to view the info that was in the paragraphs i know that. I'll try playing with the %, thnx for the answer